# polyfit max degree of polynom

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am fitting my data, and trying to find best polynome order.
Here is the code:

```
cov = 1
o = 2
print 'begin polyfit'
for z in range(15, 65):
    ttt = np.polyfit(phase3, data3, z, full=True)
    p_k_t = ttt[0]
    cov_t = ttt[1]
    if (len(cov_t)>0) and (cov_t < cov):
        p_k = p_k_t
        o = z
        cov = cov_t
print 'End polyfit, best order = ', o
```

But every time (data is changing) I get best order = 30. Fit looks not very good, can be better.
Start thinking that its a maximal value of polynom order. Can it be true ? Or then I must have error on 31 order ?

Green line is a polyfit
[image: Green line is a polyfit]

**UPDATE:**
Residuals (cov) cant be computed after order 30

Comment: Are you calculating your *error* on the same data as you are fitting the polynom? Then of course the maximum degree is chosen (maximum model capabilities / power; there is no regulization in your model except for the degree). Use [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) to select the degree. These are machine-learning basics. Read about *regulization* (and CV).

Comment: cross-validation is implemented in python ?

Comment: Check scikit-learn. There is everything you need and much much more. But again: read up the basics of ML.

Comment: If scikit-learn feels like an overkill you can modify the your code to minimize statistics that penalize overfitting (AIC, BIC, reduced chi^s, etc.)